# How to print void check/dummy check by limiting number of rows in a table on each page?

Tags: rtf

We have a requirement in BI Publisher to make a RTF template for Check Printing in PDF format. 
The sample output has divided into two parts: first is table that have invoice and amount details, second is Check itself.

In that, we now need to implement 'Void Checks' scenario.

Conditions are as follows:

1. Table and Check should be on one page(same page).
2. If the invoice count exceeds to 38, then a void check should be printed after the table with the total amount (of 38 invoices), and then the remaining invoices table should print with the Normal Check on the next page with the total payment amount(including the amount of 38 invoices too). (void check may be a dummy check with void written on it-in this case)
3. A void check should be printed in case of void payment.

I have found examples for it but everywhere they have only Void by overflow scenario. To print a dummy check, there has been no example present.

Comment: There are no attachments here

Comment: Is this with Oracle EBS?

Comment: Isn't your problem that you DO want a void check on overflow? You say that that's the only example you found. If not, what is the difference between that and what you want?